# Model binding safety with ASP.Net, EF, database first

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Brief: Binding from HTTP PUT requests to update some record. Models are scaffolded from db first EF so I'm not sure annotation is a viable solution.

I don't want people to be able to save (for example) `IsAdmin = true` to a user model on PUT request.

This article talks about annotating the models, which I like, but when updating the models from the DB, won't it blow away the annotations each time?

Is there something like DTOs that EF supports?  I can't find anything about this scenario which must be quite common.  What am I missing?

Comment: You could define ViewModel for Http Put requests which will not expose the sensitive information like `IsAdmin`, and then update the model based on the VIewModel in the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

For Model Binding, I assume you send request with form-data, if so, you could try [BindNever](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0#bindnever-attribute) like

```
public class InstructorWithDictionary
{
    [BindNever]
    public int ID { get; set; }
```

With `BindNever`, no matter what you set from `Put` request, the `IsAdmin` will not be set.